# How to create multiplethreads each with different ThreadProc() function using CreateThread()

Tags: c, windows, multithreading, winapi, createthread

I have successfully created a single thread using CreateThread().

Now I want to create 'n' number of threads but each with a different ThreadProc().

I have tried the following code but using it, 'n' number of threads are created all performing the same task (since Threadproc() function af all threads is same.)

```
    //Start the threads
for (int i=1; i<= max_number; i++) 
{
CreateThread( NULL, //Choose default security
              0, //Default stack size
              (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)&ThreadProc,
              //Routine to execute. I want this routine to be different each time as I want each  thread to perform a different functionality.
              (LPVOID) &i, //Thread parameter
              0, //Immediately run the thread
              &dwThreadId //Thread Id
            ) 
}
```

Is there any way I can create 'n' number of Threads each with a different Thread procedure?

Comment: Er... pass each one a pointer to a different thread procedure!  I'm afraid I don't understand why doing this is difficult, or what you're trying to do. Judging by the downvotes, neither does anyone else.  Can you explain what you're trying to do and why?

Comment: @DavidM : "pass each one a pointer to a different thread procedure!" I think that is what I was looking for :)
Thank you so much :)

Comment: Hah!  No worries, glad it was so simple :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
DWORD WINAPI ThreadProc1(  LPVOID lpParameter)
{
  ...
  return 0 ;
}

DWORD WINAPI ThreadProc2(  LPVOID lpParameter)
{
  ...
  return 0 ;
}

...

typedef DWORD (WINAPI * THREADPROCFN)(LPVOID lpParameter);

THREADPROCFN fntable[4] = {ThreadProc1, ThreadProc2, ...} ;

//Start the threads
for (int i = 0; i < max_number; i++) 
{
  DWORD ThreadId ;

  CreateThread( NULL,
                0,
                (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)fntable[i],
                (LPVOID) i,
                0,
                &ThreadId
              ) ;
}
```

This will start max_number threads with different thread procedures (TreadProc1, ThreadProc2, etc.) as defined in fntable.

Comment: Is it possible to create two threds with same thread Procedure call and different parameters passed to thread procedure call for each Thread.
e.g.

for thread#1, Thread Procedure is "threadProc()" and parameter is "thread1".

for thread#2, Thread Procedure is "threadProc()" and parameter is "thread2"

Comment: That's exactly what you did in your example, except that you must write "(LPVOID)i" instead of "(LPVOID)&i".

Comment: I had been trying the above mentioned code. It is compiled successfully but when the code is exxecuted, I get the error that solution.exe has stopped working. Could you suggest me a solution Please?

Comment: Unhandled exception at 0x003bf9a8 in Creating40Threads.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation.

Comment: Where does it crash ? Your debugger should tell you. Show your code.

Comment: Problem Solved by replacing  `(LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)&fntable[i]` with `(LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)fntable[i]`. I even myself don't how did this happen